# In Wasteland, why use Knife or Fists instead of Brawling?

Tags: wasteland

This is a min/max efficiency question. Are there in-game situations where it makes practical sense to have knife fight or pugilism skill instead of focusing your limited supply of skill points on brawling?

Knife applies only to knives. Pugilism applies only to fists. Brawling applies to [all other melee weapons](http://wasteland.wikia.com/wiki/Brawling), which seems very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brawling is definitely the better skill. Even ignoring the fact that knives and fists are fairly ineffective melee weapons compared to the alternatives you can use with Brawling, Brawling also doubles your number of attacks once you've purchased two levels of it. As a bonus, Brawling stays useful even if you get plenty of ranged weapons and ammo for everyone because you earn double experience points for melee kills.

In general, Wasteland has quite a few nearly-useless skills and a few more, like Knife and Pugilism, that are sub-optimal. For those who would like to avoid the pain of wasting points on bad skills, check out [this guide](http://user.tninet.se/~jyg699a/wasteland.html#char) for some suggestions on what to avoid.